# This type of file may harm your computer when i installed visual studio code on Linux. advice me download it or not?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to download VSC but chrome said that what should I do

Comment: Many people are using VS Code, if you installed it from the official source, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: I download it from this website code.visualstudio.com and I think it's the official right?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a security warning since this file is an executable. Provided you are downloading the file from the official Microsoft Visual Studio Code site [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/); then you are okay to decide and proceed to download it.